# Initial data for inline formsets of Django related models?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views, formset, inline-formset

I'm trying to create an UpdateView page that allows me to edit a customer's information as well as all affiliated users' information in a form. My CustomerForm works fine, but I'm not sure how to set the initial data for the inline formsets. I tried to get a dictionary of all users by going through `self.object.user_set.all()` with a for loop. However I can't seem to make any change to the UserFormSet. Here's my code:

forms.py

```
class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Customer
         fields = ['name', 'system', 'bill_amount', 'exchanges', 'due_date', 'invoice_date', 'keycodes_expire', 'paid_date', 'active']
         success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

UserFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Customer, User, fields=['name', 'expiration_date'], extra=1, can_delete=True)
```

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default = False)   
    bill_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)   
    due_date = models.DateField(default = timezone.now() + timedelta(days=30), blank = True, null = True)   
    exchanges = models.IntegerField(default = 0)    
    invoice_date = models.DateField(default = timezone.now(), blank = True, null = True)
    keycodes_expire = models.DateField(default = timezone.now() + timedelta(days=120), blank = True, null = True)   
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    paid_date = models.DateField(default = timezone.now() + timedelta(days=30), blank = True, null = True)
    edge_hosted = 'Edge (hosted)'
    edge_nonhosted = 'Edge (non-hosted)'
    edge_risk_hosted = 'Edge Risk (hosted)'
    edge_risk_nonhosted = 'Edge Risk (non-hosted)'
    tradepad = 'Tradepad'   
    system_choices = (
        (edge_hosted, 'Edge (hosted)'),
        (edge_nonhosted, 'Edge (non-hosted)'),
        (tradepad, 'Tradepad'),
        (edge_risk_hosted, 'Edge Risk (hosted)'),
        (edge_risk_nonhosted, 'Edge Risk (non-hosted)')
    )
    system = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices = system_choices, default = edge_hosted)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('customer-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class User(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer')
    expiration_date = models.DateField(default = timezone.now() + timedelta(days=120))  
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 64, default = 'user')
```

views.py

```
class CustomerUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Customer
    form_class = CustomerForm
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        userData = []
        for x in range(0,len(self.object.user_set.all())):
            foo = {'name' : self.object.user_set.all()[x].name, 'expiration_date' : self.object.user_set.all()[x].expiration_date}      
            userData.append(foo)
        users = inlineformset_factory(Customer, User, fields=['name', 'expiration_date'], extra=len(self.object.user_set.all()), can_delete=True)
        userList = users(queryset = self.object.user_set.all())
        ctx = super(CustomerUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            ctx['inlines'] = userList
        else:
            ctx['inlines'] = userList
        return ctx
```

customer_update_form.html

```
<h1>Update Customer</h1>
<form id="customer_form" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}   
{% for f in form %}
    <div>{{ f.label }}:<br />{{ f }}
        {% if f.errors %}
             {% for v in f.errors %}
                        <br /><span style="color:red;">{{ v }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
{% endfor %}
<h2>Update User(s)</h2>
<table>
{% for f2 in inlines %}
    <tr id="{{ f2.prefix }}-row-0">
            <td>
                {{ f2.name.label }}: 
            {{ f2.name }}
        {% if f2.name.errors %}
            <span style="color:red;">{{ f2.name.errors }}</span>
        {% endif %}
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="{{ f2.prefix }}-row-1">
        <td>
            {{ f2.expiration_date.label }}: 
            {{ f2.expiration_date }}
        {% if f2.expiration_date.errors %}
            <span style="color:red;">{{ f2.expiration_date.errors }}</span>
        {% endif %}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="{{ f2.prefix }}-row-2">
        <td>
            {{ f2.DELETE.label }}? 
            {{ f2.DELETE }}
        {% if f2.DELETE.errors %}
            <span style="color:red;">{{ f2.DELETE.errors }}</span>
        {% endif %}
        </td>
    </tr>
    {{ f2.as_p }}
{% endfor %}
</table>
{{ inlines.management_form }}
<input type="submit" value="Create Customer / User(s)" />
```

I just want the usernames and expiration dates to be initial values in each formset, but accessing the users and their fields seems near impossible, and changing values for the users doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

change in your views:

```
userList = users(
    queryset=self.object.user_set.all(),
    instance=self.object
)
```

Also you cannot have request.POST in get_context_data - it is absurd! remove this `if self.request.POST:` from `get_context_data`

If you want save data you should implement it in `post method`

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk_url_kwarg:
            self.object = self.get_object()
            form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=self.object)
            inlines = users(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=self.object)
        else:
            form = self.form_class(request.POST)
            inlines = users(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid() and inlines.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, inlines)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, inlines)



 def form_valid(self, form, inlines):
        if not self.object:
            self.object = form.save()
        else:
            form.save()

        inlines.instance = self.object
        inlines.save()


        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())



def form_invalid(self, form, inlines):
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(
                form=form,
                inlines=inlines
            )
        )

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('some_app:url_name')
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for the most part. I had to change `userFormSet` to a class variable and set userList (from get_context_data) & inLines (from post) to `self.userFormSet`. However, submitting the form causes an extra user to be saved and submitted when submitting for the first time, any idea what's causing this? I tried changing my formset to `{{ f2.as_p }}` instead of the written out way I had previously but it didn't work.

Comment: It's my fault :D remove `form.save()` from `form_valid` method. You need save only `inlines`

Comment: Ok, I see now how it all works. I'm keeping `form.save()` because otherwise I can't update any of the customer information, just users. In order to avoid extra users being added, I set the `extra=0`. If I wanted to have extras that didn't get submitted, I could change the formset or make a dynamic formset with a 'add user' button